# cursor.getString(index_col) from bool index in sqlite

Tags: string, sqlite, boolean

I have this huge problem. There is this table I created but made one index into bool. I used a `Question.setAnswer(c.getString(2));` to make the bool index table into string it returns True  if True and False if False. Here is the log `Answer found in DB: True` and this is the code behind it: `Log.d("QUESTION", "Answer Found in DB: " + c.getString(2));` This is where it gets confusing.

`if(Question.getAnswer() == "True") Question.rightCo++`

but no matter what the value of `Question.getAnswer()` it doesn't increment the `rightCo`

What seems to be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: What language are you using? What is target? What is table schema? What kind of object is `Question`? ...

Comment: I'm using java eclipse with android. Question is a class with static variables. The table schema, I seriously don't know I just copied that code from a sample sourcecode of a fully working app

Comment: `Question.getAnswer()` is method, not a variable. There's not enough information to help you.

Comment: `Question.getAnswer()` is a `public static getAnswer()` and when i tested it in the log `Log.d("answer", Question.getAnswer());` it returns this `True`

Comment: Does it returns `"True"` (string), `true` (boolean) or `TRUE` (Boolean)? Try `Question.getAnswer() == TRUE` and `Question.getAnswer() == true`.

Comment: it returns `"True"`(string) but it doesn't seem to be able to satisfy the `if(Question.getAnswer() == "True")`